# no value for username when parsing json data

Tags: android, json

### RegisterActivity.java

> This is register Activity and use of Asyntask class for json parsing **I got error when i submitted data to the server** *and when i submitted data then no value for UserName* is occued.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText etUsername, etUserEmalAdd, etUserPass, etRe_enterPass;
    Switch aSwitch;
    TextView tvLoginLink;
    Button bRegister;
    Context con;
    String userName,EmailAdd,password,Confirm_Pass;
    String UserName = "",Email = "",Password = "";
    String RegisterMessage = "", RegisterMessageInfo = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        declareData();

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                userName = etUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                EmailAdd = etUserEmalAdd.getText().toString().trim();
                password = md5(etUserPass.getText().toString().trim());
                Confirm_Pass = md5(etRe_enterPass.getText().toString().trim());

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)
                        ||TextUtils.isEmpty(EmailAdd)
                        ||TextUtils.isEmpty(password)
                        ||TextUtils.isEmpty(Confirm_Pass)
                        ||(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(EmailAdd).matches())
                        ||(!Confirm_Pass.equals(password))){

                    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(EmailAdd).matches()){
                        etUserEmalAdd.requestFocus();
                        etUserEmalAdd.setError("Required..!!");
                    }
                    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(EmailAdd)){
                        etUserEmalAdd.requestFocus();
                        etUserEmalAdd.setError("Required..!!");
                    }
                    else{

                    }


                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                        etUserPass.requestFocus();
                        etUserPass.setError("Required..!!");
                    }
                    else{

                    }

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Confirm_Pass)){
                        etRe_enterPass.requestFocus();
                        etRe_enterPass.setError("Required..!!");
                    }
                    else if (!(password.equals(Confirm_Pass))){
                        etRe_enterPass.requestFocus();
                        etRe_enterPass.setError("Both password should be same..!!");
                    }
                    else {

                    }

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)){
                        etUsername.requestFocus();
                        etUsername.setError("Required..!!");
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }
                else {
                    new RegisterCheckTask().execute();
                }
            }
        });

        tvLoginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(con,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_register, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void declareData(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        con = RegisterActivity.this;

        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etUserEmalAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserEmail);
        etUserPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserPassword);
        etRe_enterPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserReenterPassword);

        aSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchd);

        tvLoginLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLoginLink);

        bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterUser);
    }


    class RegisterCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog p_dialog;

        JSONObject jObject;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            p_dialog = new ProgressDialog(con);
            p_dialog.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
            p_dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            p_dialog.setCancelable(false);
            p_dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {

            jObject = JSONParser.RegisterNewUser(etUsername.getText().toString(),
                    etUserEmalAdd.getText().toString(), md5(etUserPass.getText().toString()));

            Log.d("TAG", "JSON OBJECTSSSSSSS : " + jObject);
            Log.d("TAG","RegisterMessage:"+RegisterMessage);
            String msg = "Nothing Happened...";
            try {
                if (jObject != null) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "RESULT " + jObject.getString("status"));
                    Log.d("TAG", "RESULT Info:" + jObject.getString("message"));

                    RegisterMessage = jObject.getString("status");
                    RegisterMessageInfo = jObject.getString("message");

                    UserName = jObject.getString("UserName");
                    Email = jObject.getString("Email");
                    Password = md5(jObject.getString("Password"));

                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Login Time Already Syncd....");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("TAG", "Warn :" + e.getLocalizedMessage());

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            p_dialog.dismiss();
            //here is error
            //i get result is null
            Log.d("TAG:","REsultttttt:"+result);
            if (RegisterMessage == null || RegisterMessage.equals("false"))
                ShowErroMessage("Not Registerd",
                        "Please try Again Later");
            else {
                if (RegisterMessage.equals("true")) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(con, FistLoginPageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                } else {
                    ShowErroMessage(RegisterMessage, RegisterMessageInfo);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ShowErroMessage(String message, String messageInfo) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);
        View promptView2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_error_message,
                null);
        final Dialog dialogDisplayParameter2 = new Dialog(con,
                R.style.FullHeightDialog);
        dialogDisplayParameter2.setContentView(promptView2);
        dialogDisplayParameter2.show();

        ((TextView) promptView2.findViewById(R.id.tvErrorMessageHeading))
                .setText(message);

        ((TextView) promptView2.findViewById(R.id.tvErrorMessageText))
                .setText(messageInfo);

        ((Button) promptView2.findViewById(R.id.btnErrorMessageOk))
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialogDisplayParameter2.cancel();
                        if (RegisterMessage
                                .equals("succeed")) {
                            //Log.d("RegisterMessage:",RegisterMessage);
                            Intent i = new Intent(con, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    private static final String md5(final String password) {
        try {

            MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                    .getInstance("MD5");
            digest.update(password.getBytes());
            byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
                String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                while (h.length() < 2)
                    h = "0" + h;
                hexString.append(h);
            }
            Log.d("MD5", hexString.toString());
            return hexString.toString();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

### JsonParser.java

```
package com.ninja.mock.ninjamockapplication.parser;


import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by Shreeya Patel on 12/28/2015.
 */

public class JSONParser {

    static String SITE_URL = "https://api.otentik.id/post/";

    static String url;
    static String result;
    static HttpPost httpPost;
    static HttpClient httpClient;
    static JSONObject jsonObject;
    static JSONArray jsonArray;
    static HttpEntity httpEntity;
    static InputStream is;
    static HttpResponse httpResponse;
    static List<NameValuePair> pairs;
    static String json = "";


/**
     * Initialization of Variables
     */

    private static void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result = "";
        jsonObject = null;
        httpPost = null;
        is = null;
        jsonArray = null;
        httpClient = getNewHttpClient();
    }

    private static String getResult(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();

    }
    public static JSONObject RegisterNewUser(String UserName,
                                             String Email,
                                             String Password) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            init();

            url = SITE_URL + "register/ortu";
            Log.d("TAG", url);
            httpPost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
           /* httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");*/

            Log.d("TAG", "IN ADD USER JSON PARSING  : " + UserName + "\n" + Email + "\n" + Password);
            Log.d("TAG", "HTTP POST" + httpPost);
            pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserName", UserName));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", Email));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", Password));

            Log.d("TAG", "IN ADD USER JSON PARSING  : " + UserName + "\n" + Email + "\n" + Password);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

            Log.d("TAG", "HTTP POST" + httpPost);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            int responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.d("TAG", "HTTP RESPONSE Code" + responseCode);
            Log.d("TAG", "HTTP RESPONSE" + httpResponse);
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

/* Convert response to string */

            result = getResult(is);
            Log.d("TAG", "RESULTTTTTTTTTTTTT : " + result);
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            Log.d("TAG", "JSON OBJECT : " + jsonObject);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Error in Client Protocol : " + e.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Error Parsing data " + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Error in HTTP Connection : " + e.toString());
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "JSON OBJECTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT : " + jsonObject);
        return jsonObject;
    }

    public static HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            MySSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Share the logcat message

Comment: you should use and condition instead of or as it will be executed if any field contains value

Comment: 12-31 12:10:16.723    3306-3450/com.ninja.mock.ninjamockapplication E/TAG﹕ Warn :No value for UserName

Comment: Could you add server response JSON in your question?

Comment: plz give me example line of server response JSON @harism

Comment: i share my logcat screen @ajantha

Comment: This is the line on LogCat showing your JSON response from server ; __3306-3450/com.ninja.mock.ninjamockapplication D/TAG﹕ JSON OBJECT : {"status":false,"message":"email sudah terdaftar"}__ .